# Parse CSV, Convert, and Sort as Array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, csv

I am working through a coding challenge, and am stuck trying to sort my data.

The challenge is to:

1. Parse the data and find only rows where user started before 9/6/10.
2. Order the "start_dates" in ascending order.
3. Return/Print the resulting phrase from the "words" column.

I am able to get the correct words, but not in the correct order.

The start_dates need to be sorted in ascending order so the words will display in the right order.

Here's my code:

```
require 'CSV'

csvFile = 'tse.csv'

CSV.foreach(csvFile) do |row|
  int = row[13].to_i
  words = []
  if int < 1283731200
    words.push(row[16])
  end
  puts words
end
```

**Note:** `1283731200` is the Unix timestamp for the date I need.

How can I sort `row[13]`? Every combination of the sort method, but get back one of these errors:

> undefined method 'sort' for 0:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
>
> undefined method 'sort' for "start_date":String (NoMethodError)

CSV snippet:

```
id,created_at,first_name,last_name,email,gender,company,currency,drug_brand,drug_name,drug_company,pill_color,frequency,start_date,end_date,other,words,bitcoin,word
676,1351140260,Charles,Rice,crice49@i2i.jp,Male,Realbuzz,MDL,Nortriptyline Hydrochloride,Nortriptyline Hydrochloride,"Physicians Total Care, inc.",Maroon,monthly,1409564900,1331661153,Monthly,aliquet,1AeYC1Cc49p7J5hFqUcsgJFjXb5Pqa68AQ,",./;'[]\-="
2002,1540878657,Margaret,Day,mdaydp@salon.com,Female,Devbug,IDR,RENOKIN HAIR REVITALIZING CONDITIONER,Dimethicone,"Caregen Co., Ltd.",Yellow,monthly,1458457018,1533561260,Weekly,cursus,164X1tNoUguVA8Xpg2vnp3cfYzhTRGxwoN,<svg><script>0<1>alert('XSS')</script>
3324,1589084473,Anthony,Collins,acollinsil@java.com,Male,Avamm,EUR,FRUITOPIA,PYRITHIONE ZINC,CVS PHARMACY,Blue,weekly,1333192422,1520700521,Never,pharetra,15oqV5seTTsQZDJhagJoU2z5hB9m7QCRAj,�_��_ۑ�Ӓ�ʑ��
```

Comment: can you provide a small sample of the csv file? so we know what we are working with

Comment: gladly, but how? i don't want to copy pasta a bunch of random text.

Comment: just a couple of riows will do.

Comment: and also, where did you call the `sort`? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: yeah, i removed it because I couldn't get it to work. I tried various places.

Answer (score 0):

So, I modified the starting date of the first two rows so that they fall inside the time restriction.

For reference, here is the csv file I used.

```
id,created_at,first_name,last_name,email,gender,company,currency,drug_brand,drug_name,drug_company,pill_color,frequency,start_date,end_date,other,words,bitcoin,word
676,1351140260,Charles,Rice,crice49@i2i.jp,Male,Realbuzz,MDL,Nortriptyline Hydrochloride,Nortriptyline Hydrochloride,"Physicians Total Care, inc.",Maroon,monthly,1209564900,1331661153,Monthly,aliquet,1AeYC1Cc49p7J5hFqUcsgJFjXb5Pqa68AQ,",./;'[]\-="
2002,1540878657,Margaret,Day,mdaydp@salon.com,Female,Devbug,IDR,RENOKIN HAIR REVITALIZING CONDITIONER,Dimethicone,"Caregen Co., Ltd.",Yellow,monthly,1158457018,1533561260,Weekly,cursus,164X1tNoUguVA8Xpg2vnp3cfYzhTRGxwoN,<svg><script>0<1>alert('XSS')</script>
3324,1589084473,Anthony,Collins,acollinsil@java.com,Male,Avamm,EUR,FRUITOPIA,PYRITHIONE ZINC,CVS PHARMACY,Blue,weekly,1333192422,1520700521,Never,pharetra,15oqV5seTTsQZDJhagJoU2z5hB9m7QCRAj,�_��_ۑ�Ӓ�ʑ��
```

A couple of problems with your code

1) You declared `words = []` inside the `foreach` loop, so it resets each time. You don't want that.

2) You are not keeping tracking of the starting date for each of the values you push into the `words` array.

3) The first line of the csv file is headings, you are not taking that into account in your code.

Here's what I did

```
require 'csv'

csvFile = 'test.csv'
words = {}
CSV.foreach(csvFile) do |row|
  next if row[0] == 'id'

  int = row[13].to_i
  if int < 1283731200
    words[row[13]] = row[16]
  end
end
words = words.sort.map(&:last) #=> ["cursus", "aliquet"]
```

I used a hash in this case. so you have a key-value pair of `starting_date => word`.

The line `next if row[0] == 'id` checks if we are on the first row. If so, skip to the next iteration.

Then, the last line, I sort the hash, which returns an array in the form of `[[starting_date1, word1], [starting_date2, word2]...]`, and I use `map` to select the last values, which are the words you want, so you end up with an array of words in ascending order by starting date.

Comment: Awesome - I think the hash idea made a low of sense in this case. This worked for me.

The only thing I changed was removing the `next if row[0] == 'id'` line. 

Instead I added `CSV.foreach(csvFile, headers: true)`

Thanks!